# How to filter fields present inside an array

Tags: json, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I want to fetch fields inside an array in my data.

```
{
  dept: "ADF"
  properties: [
     {
       id: "123",
       name : "john",

     },
     {
       id: "234",
       name: "Bob"
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the `name` field only when `id` = "sid"

```
"{\"selector\":{\"id\":{\"$elemMatch\":"{\"id\":\"%s\"}},\"fields\": [\"properties.[].name\",\"dept\"]}"
```

The data is filtered but I'm not getting the `name` field in the filtered data.

Comment: CouchDB doesn't support what you want, which is akin the MongoDB's `$aggregate/$group` feature.  A workaround to is to apply a simple transformation to the result documents to get the data in the required form. It would be easier if  `properties` weren't an array, e.g. `properties:{ '123': { 'name': 'John' }}`.

Comment: Have you considered writing a view instead of using a mango query?

Comment: @JoshuaBeckers no.Actually i'm not sure if it is supported for hyperledger fabric.As per the documentation i could only see selectors